# Uploading MS Access records from local machine

Tags: ms-access, ftp, vba

I need a way of uploading MS Access records from a local machine to a MS Access database that is located on a web server.

Ideally, I would use a simple VBA interface with an "Upload all new records" button, which would then connect the FTP (username, pwd) and insert the records into the centralised database.

Is this possible?  If not, does anyone know of a straightforward solution?  We wish to use MS Access for its user friendliness...

Thanks in advance,
AC.

Comment: You could do it in two stages, upload the records in a file (csv for example) via FTP, kick off some script to add the records.

Comment: You should specify in your question if your host is ASP capable or PHP only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to use an ADO [Recordset.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to save a persistent recordset on the client (non-web) side, and then POST that recordset to the Web server (the POST could be done using an MSXML2.XMLHTTP object on the client-side)

Once the Web server receives the POST, then you could use an ASP script with an ADO [Recordset.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open it up and populate the database.

**EDIT** - Attaching some sample code. I tested this and it seems to work quite well.  The hardest part may be configuring your Web server to be able to read the Access database; however I think as long as you have it in the same folder as your ASP script you will be OK.

Note your table structure on both sides must be exactly the same.

I just re-read your post and realized you wanted to use FTP. This is a Web (http, ASP-only) solution.  If you *have* to use FTP, you *could* download the entire database, update it, and send it back. You could also FTP a persistent recordset in a text file and periodically check for updates in that folder, importing them when new files are found.

Client (non-web side) MS-Access code:

```
Sub ClientSide()
    'Used CreateObject in lieu of the lines below,
    'so you can run this code without references.

'    Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
'    Dim oStream As ADODB.Stream
'    Dim oXMLHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP

    Dim oRS, oStream, oXMLHTTP

    Set oRS = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("SELECT * FROM [MyClientTable]")
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oRS.Save oStream, 1

    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    oXMLHTTP.Open "POST", "http://myserver:80/path/to/asp/server.asp", False, "username", "password"
    oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
    oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2"

    sXML = oStream.ReadText

    oXMLHTTP.send sXML
    'The web server's response is in oXMLHTTP.responseText. You may need it for debugging.
    If oXMLHTTP.status <> 200 Then
        'This should pop up some useful information if the POST request fails.

        Set app = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        app.Visible = True
        app.Navigate "about:blank"
        app.Document.Write oXMLHTTP.responseText
    End If

    oRS.Close
End Sub
```

Server (web-side) ASP page "server.asp":

```
<%
    sXML = Request.Form

    'Database is in the same folder as the asp page
    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\path\to\script\serverdb.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;"
    Set oStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.WriteText sXML
    oStream.Position = 0

    Set oRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    oRS.Open oStream

    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [MyServerTable]"
    Set oDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    oDB.Open sSQL, sConn, 1, 3

    'There's probably a more elegant/quick way of inserting the records,
    'but this should be a good start.
    Do While Not oRS.Eof
        oDB.AddNew
        For Each f in oRS.fields
            oDB.Fields(f.Name).Value = f.Value
        Next
        oRS.MoveNext
        oDB.Update
    Loop
    oDB.Close
    oRS.Close

    Response.write "Done"

%>
```

@iDevlop is correct in stating that an Access database is not a great Web-side DBMS, but it should be OK as long as you have a low volume of users.

Comment: Thanks folks - I think I'll give the ASP approach a shot!  Thanks for all the help!  AC.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a *straightforward solution* to this, so:

*suggestion 1*: can't you download the Access db, update it locally, then send it back ?
otherwise,
*suggestion 2*: use ms Access "for its user friendliness" as a local interface if you want, but link that to a SQL Server or mySQL (whatever is available on your host).

Comment: I think Suggestion 2 is probably the best route.  Access makes a great interface to SQL Server, and it is decent for single user database applications, but it does not handle multiple users or backing up a large application nearly as well as other RDBMS's like SQL Server do.